# selecting row only if column value appears in fixed order (oracle)

Tags: oracle

```
TABLE A:

ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC ColumnD
77777     89      ABC   11:33:01
77777     88      ABC   11:33:09

77776     89      ABC   10:00:01
77776     88      ABC   10:34:01
77776     87      ABC   10:35:10

77775     88      ABC   11:32:48
77775     89      ABC   11:33:09
77775     61      DEF   11:38:21
```

As a result i need to select two rows 77777 and 77776 only as the 77775 has 88

value as first and 89 as second whereas the expectation is vice versa

i have this query(The query allows me to select row only when both 89 and 88

coexist but there is need to check the order in which they appear):

```
select ta.COLUMNA from TABLEA ta 
where ta.COLUMNB in (89,88) 
group by ta.COLUMNA 
having count(distint ta.COLUMNB)=2;
```

This will select me all the results in above table

Comment: Define "order in which they appear".  A heap organized table is by definition unordered.  You can only talk about "frist", "last", "before" and "after" in the context of an `order by` clause that provides the ordering.  What `order by` do you want to use here?  It's not obvious from the data that you provided how you are determining the order.  Is there another date column that you've left off that provides the order?

Comment: Yes, there is date in asc order. Edited in my query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can solve this with a join to itself, in the form of

```
SELECT JOINTABLEA.COLUMNA FROM TABLEA JOINTABLEA
JOIN TABLEA JOINTABLEB 
ON JOINTABLEB.COLUMND > JOINTABLEA.COLUMND
WHERE JOINTABLEA.COLUMNB = 89
AND JOINTABLEB.COLUMNB = 88
GROUP BY JOINTABLEA.COLUMNA
```

I've made a small SQLFiddle example [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b69b0/4), although I just used numbers instead of a datetime column for ColumnD